# Adding system call to linux-6.2.8

Tags: c, linux, makefile, operating-system, kernel

I was trying to add a custom system callnamed hello to Linux kernel version 6.2.8. I saw on articles online that I need to add `core-y += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ hello/` to my Makefile. But the Makefile in 6.2.8 looks like
`ifeq ($(KBUILD_EXTMOD),)  core-y       :=   drivers-y  :=  libs-y      := lib/  endif`  
What changes I need to make in this Makefile to make the system call work.

I was expecting Makefile to look like `core-y += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/` but I got it in a different format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.